# NSolve can't solve a system of 2 equations with 2 unknowns

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, numerical-value

I've been trying to solve a system of 2 equations with 2 unknowns using NSolve. But It's been too slow. I waited for more then an hour without any results.

The code is:

```
as=50
ad=70
Na=10000
l = 5.55238*10^(-7)
A1 = 5.291772109*10^(-11)
h2 = 32/3*Sqrt[\[Pi]]*(as*A1)^(5/2)/l^(5/2)*Na^(1/2)*4*Re[NIntegrate[(1 - ad/as + 3 *ad/as* u^2)^(5/2), {u, 0, 1}]]
H2 = 12/25*Sqrt[2/5]*h2/(\[Pi]^(9/4))
AS = as/l*A1
AD=ad/l*A1
eq1 = FullSimplify[-1/(a/l)^3 - Sqrt[2/\[Pi]]*Na/((a/l)^3*c/l)*(AS - AD*((2 - 7*(a^2/c^2) + 9*(a^4/c^4)*ArcTanh[Sqrt[1 - (a^2/c^2)]]/Sqrt[1 - (a^2/c^2)] - 4*(a^4/c^4))/(2*(1 - (a^2/c^2))^2))) - H2*1/((a/l)^4*(c/l)^(3/2))]
eq2 = FullSimplify[-1/(c/l)^3 - Sqrt[2/\[Pi]]*Na/((a/l)^2*(c/l)^2)*(AS - AD*((1 + 10*(a^2/c^2) - 9*(a^2/c^2)*ArcTanh[Sqrt[1 - (a^2/c^2)]]/Sqrt[1 - (a^2/c^2)] - 2*(a^4/c^4))/(1-(a^2/c^2))^2)) -H2*1/((a/l)^3*(c/l)^(5/2))]
NSolve[eq1 == 0 && eq2 == 0, {a, c}]
```

This is my first time writing mathematica code in stackexchange so hopefully I didn't make any mistake. Like I said, when I run NSolve, I can't get a solution even if it's running for more than an hour. Am I making some kind of stupid mistake (like maybe I need to symplify my equations further) or is NSolve not great with these kind of equations.

Just to add, those equations are from Bose-Einstein condensation and variables a and c represents lenghts, that means they are >0

Comment: Your system of equations has infinite many solutions for `a==c`. I.e. solutions are not isolated and lie on line `a==c` and `NSolve` is not good in such cases. It is good when there are several isolated points of solution.

Comment: Is there something that can be done to fix that, maybe add a condition that a=/=c or something?

Comment: The part that is slowing down everything is part with AD*(.....) element. Without it, NSolve works fast.